# How do I change <NavLink /> default styling in material-ui-next?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I'm creating a navigation bar. Here are some styles:

```
  flex: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  ulStyles: {
    listStyleType: 'none',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
  liItem: {
    marginLeft: 20,
  },
  active: {
    textDecoration: 'underline white',
  },
```

Here's the fragment from AppBar ([source](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/app-bar/)):

```
  <Typography type="title" color="inherit" className={classes.flex}>
    <ul className={classes.ulStyles}>
      <li className={classes.liItem}>Home</li>
      <li className={classes.liItem}><NavLink exact activeClassName={classes.active} to='/'>Home</NavLink></li>
      <li className={classes.liItem}><NavLink activeClassName={classes.active} to='/battle'>Battle</NavLink></li>
      <li className={classes.liItem}><NavLink activeClassName={classes.active} to='/popular'>Popular</NavLink> </li>
    </ul>
  </Typography>
```

Here's the result:
[image]

How can I get rid of that `<NavLink />` default styling?

I'm tiring to override with inline style:

```
const navLink = {
    color: '#ffffff',
    textDecoration: 'none',
};
```

`<li className={classes.liItem}><NavLink  exact activeClassName={classes.active} to='/' style={navLink}>Home</NavLink></li>`

but now the tabs get white and my

```
  active: {
    textDecoration: 'underline white',
  },
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material UI allows two ways to do this:

1. Override the styles with classes:

When the className property isn't enough, and you need to access deeper elements, you can take advantage of the classes property to customize all the CSS injected by Material-UI for a given component. The list of classes for each component is documented in the Component API section. For instance, you can have a look at the Button CSS API. Alternatively, you can always look at the implementation details.

This example also uses withStyles() (see above), but OverridesClasses is using Button's classes prop to provide an array containing the names of classes to override (keys), and the CSS class names to apply (values). The component's existing classes will continue to be injected, so it is only necessary to provide the specific styles you wish to add or override.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';

const styles = {
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    borderRadius: 3,
    border: 0,
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .30)',
  },
  label: {
    textTransform: 'capitalize',
  },
};

function OverridesClasses(props) {
  return (
    <Button
      classes={{
        root: props.classes.root, // className, e.g. `OverridesClasses-root-X`
        label: props.classes.label, // className, e.g. `OverridesClasses-label-X`
      }}
    >
      {props.children ? props.children : 'classes'}
    </Button>
  );
}

OverridesClasses.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(OverridesClasses);
```

2. Overriding with inline-style:

The second way to override the style of a component is to use the inline-style approach. Every component provides a style property. These properties are always applied to the root element.

You don't have to worry about CSS specificity as the inline-style takes precedence over the regular CSS.

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';

// We can use inline-style
const style = {
  background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
  borderRadius: 3,
  border: 0,
  color: 'white',
  height: 48,
  padding: '0 30px',
  boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .30)',
};

function OverridesInlineStyle() {
  return <Button style={style}>inline-style</Button>;
}

export default OverridesInlineStyle;
```

https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/

Comment: thanks, I tried to override with inline styles but doesn't work. I have updated my post.